# Bower does not install the latest version of angular-bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bower, bower-install

I have noticed that I've been using angular-bootstrap 0.14.3 on a project and when I tried to find out the reason, I couldn't.

My `bower.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "",
        "components-font-awesome": "",
        "ionicons": "",
        "angular": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-aria": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-messages": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
        "angular-fullscreen": "",
        "angular-bootstrap": "",
        "angular-file-saver": "",
        "angular-strap": "",
        "angular-utils-ui-breadcrumbs": "",
        "api-check": "",
        "angular-formly": "",
        "angular-formly-templates-bootstrap": "",
        "datatables.net": "",
        "datatables.net-bs": "",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs": "",
        "angular-datatables": "",
        "angular-ui-grid": "",
        "angular-ui-mask": "",
        "ui-router": "0.2.15",
        "angular-ui-select": "",
        "angular-ui-router-tabs": "",
        "international-phone-number": "",
        "ngCountrySelectJs": "",
        "ng-currency": "",
        "lodash": "",
        "angular-wizard": "",
        "satellizer": "",
        "ngprogress": "",
        "angular-ui-notification": "",
        "material-design-iconic-font": "1.0",
        "dropzone": "",
        "angular-ladda": "",
        "angular-loading-spinner": "",
        "ng-slide-down": "",
        "angular-flippy": "",
        "angular-print": "",
        "angular-base64-upload": ""
    },
    "overrides": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "main": ["dist/js/bootstrap.js", "dist/css/bootstrap.css", "less/bootstrap.less"]
        },
        "ngprogress": {
            "main": ["build/ngprogress.js", "ngProgress.css"]
        },
        "country-select-js": {
            "main": ["build/js/countrySelect.min.js", "build/css/countrySelect.min.css"]
        },
        "datatables": {
            "main": []
        },
        "material-design-iconic-font": {
            "main": ["css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css"]
        }
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "angular": "^1.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
    },
    "appPath": "app",
    "moduleName": "app"
}
```

Using `bower install` or `bower update` the version of angular-bootstrap that gets installed is 0.14.3. When I tried to install version 1.3.2 explicitly, I got the following error:

```
bower ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular-bootstrap
```

Am I missing something here?